# Вывод значения переменной в поле Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как вывести значение переменной s в поле Text и можно ли вообще это сделать?

Comment: `textfield.insert(END, text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import*

w = Tk()
t = Text(w)
t.insert(END, 'hello') #like this
t.pack()
w.mainloop()
```