# код выдает такую ошибку return self.func(*args)

Tags: python

```
import tkinter as tk

def func():
    b1=float(tol_korg.get())
    b2=float(tol_plac.get())
    b3=float(tol_kysh.get())
    a11=float(_55_korg.get())
    a12=float(_55_plac.get())
    a13=float(_55_kysh.get())
    a21=float(_60_korg.get())
    a22=float(_60_plac.get())
    a23=float(_60_kysh.get())
    a31=float(_75_korg.get())
    a32=float(_75_plac.get())
    a33=float(_75_kysh.get())
    n=a11*a22*a33+a12*a23*a31+a13*a21*a32-a31*a22*a13-a32*a23*a11-a33*a21*a12
    x1=b1*a22*a33+b2*a23*a31+b3*a21*a32-a31*a22*b3-a32*a23*b1-a33*a21*b2
    x2=a11*b2*a33+a12*b3*a31+a13*b1*a32-a31*b2*a13-a32*b3*a11-a33*b1*a12
    x3=a11*a22*b3+a12*a23*b1+a13*a21*b2-b1*a22*a13-b2*a23*a11-b3*a21*a12
    nat_55_.config(format(x1/n))
    nat_60_.config(format(x2/n))
    nat_75_.config(format(x3/n))


root = tk.Tk()

root.title("ЕСЕПТЕУ БАҒДАРЛАМАСЫ")
root.geometry("700x300+500+200")
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)



a = tk.Entry(width = 5, font = "Arial 15")


korg = tk.Label(root,text = "ҚОРҒАСЫН")
korg.place(x = 10, y = 35)
plac = tk.Label(root,text = "ПЛАСТМАС")
plac.place(x = 10, y = 70)
kysh = tk.Label(root,text = "ҚЫШҚЫЛ")
kysh.place(x = 10, y = 105)
tol = tk.Label(root,text = "ТОЛЫҚ")
tol.place(x = 150, y = 15)
_55 = tk.Label(root,text = "55")
_55.place(x = 300, y = 17.5)
_60 = tk.Label(root,text = "60")
_60.place(x = 450, y = 17.5)
_75 = tk.Label(root,text = "75")
_75.place(x = 600, y = 17.5)
tol_korg = tk.Entry(root,width = 15)
tol_korg.place(x = 125, y = 35)
tol_plac = tk.Entry(root,width = 15)
tol_plac.place(x = 125, y = 70)
tol_kysh = tk.Entry(root,width = 15)
tol_kysh.place(x = 125, y = 105)
_55_korg = tk.Entry(root,width = 15)
_55_korg.place(x = 265, y = 35)
_55_plac = tk.Entry(root,width = 15)
_55_plac.place(x = 265, y = 70)
_55_kysh = tk.Entry(root,width = 15)
_55_kysh.place(x = 265, y = 105)
_60_korg = tk.Entry(root,width = 15)
_60_korg.place(x = 415, y = 35)
_60_plac = tk.Entry(root,width = 15)
_60_plac.place(x = 415, y = 70)
_60_kysh = tk.Entry(root,width = 15)
_60_kysh.place(x = 415, y = 105)
_75_korg = tk.Entry(root,width = 15)
_75_korg.place(x = 565, y = 35)
_75_plac = tk.Entry(root,width = 15)
_75_plac.place(x = 565, y = 70)
_75_kysh = tk.Entry(root,width = 15)
_75_kysh.place(x = 565, y = 105)
nat = tk.Label(root,text = "НӘТИЖЕ")
nat.place(x = 265, y = 170)
nat_55_ = tk.Text(root,bg = "white", fg = "black", width = 10, height = 1)
nat_55_.place(x = 325, y = 170)
nat_60_ = tk.Text(root,bg = "white", fg = "black", width = 10, height = 1)
nat_60_.place(x = 450, y = 170)
nat_75_ = tk.Text(root,bg = "white", fg = "black", width = 10, height = 1)
nat_75_.place(x = 575, y = 170)
btn = tk.Button(root,text = "Есептеу",width = 15, height = 1, command = func )
btn.place(x = 565, y = 210)



root.mainloop()
```

этот код выдает такую ошибку

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\77771\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\77771\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\123.py", line 20, in func
    nat_55_.config(format(x1/n))
  File "C:\Users\77771\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1675, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\77771\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1664, in _configure
    return self._getconfigure1(_flatten((self._w, cmd, '-'+cnf)))
  File "C:\Users\77771\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1652, in _getconfigure1
    x = self.tk.splitlist(self.tk.call(*args))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-50.0"
```

Comment: Что вы имели в виду в строках вида `nat_55_.config(format(x1/n))`? В config нужно передавать опцию которую вы меняете, равно, потом ее значение, например `nat_55_.config(text="какой-то текст")` (c Text это вроде бы не работает, нужно через insert добавлять текст).

Comment: этим я хотел вывести чило которое получилось x1/n

Comment: См. [Вывод значения переменной в поле Text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1105924/1365)